# Copy a text field data into a look field type

Tags: c#

I am new in coding world :) it would be helpful if somebody can help me with my below query.
We have created two custom entity called Sector and Sub sector which are having an 1:N relationship with Account. Since they are relation fields hence they are lookup type and populated on the Account form.
On another part, we have InsideView( 3rd party tool) integrated with our Contact and account form. We have mapped certain fields from Inside view with CRM fields to update the data from the inside view when it is being synced however Inside view does not support Lookup type field hence we cannot map lookup field type data.

We discovered this barrier recently when we tried to map our custom entity (sector and Subsector) with inside view. Since we cannot map lookup field type we thought to have two text field instead and map it with Inside view. Once data is synced these two text fields will get filled out with the sector and subsector name.

Now, we want to copy information from text fields to the lookup field (custom fields Sector and Sub sector)
thanks in advance for your help :)
Bhavesh

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding your requirement but you can fill a lookup field with some text.
Use following code:

```
function setLookupField() {
    var context = Xrm.Page.context;
    var UserID = context.getUserId();// your id
    var UserName=context.getUserName();//your text
    var lookupData = new Array();
    var lookupItem = new Object()`enter code here`;
    //Set the GUID
    lookupItem.id = UserID;
    //Set the name
    lookupItem.name = UserName;
    lookupItem.entityType = "systemuser";// entity name of lookup
    lookupData[0] = lookupItem;

    //If existing value is empty, then set new value
    var existingValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_usercreatedby").getValue();

    if (existingValue === null) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_usercreatedby").setValue([{
            id: UserID,
            name: UserName,
            entityType: "systemuser"
        }]);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```